# Drywall Patch & Paint Question

Tags: painting, patching-drywall, primer

Good day. I had to cut a piece of drywall on the ceiling to run some electrical. I used the same drywall patch (that I cut out) to repair the hole in the ceiling. I used mesh tape and joint compound (USG Plus3) to repair the hole.

Since the drywall is not new (had paint on it), do I need to primer the patch or can I just paint over it?

If I should primer, what would be the best primer for my situation?

Comment: Even if the drywall itself already was painted, you are putting compound over it, which is unprimed. You should prime at a minimum the area of the patch, if not reprime and repaint the whole wall. See proposed duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. The article linked is a great resource but it didn't specifically state whether the patches were new drywall or existing (painted). Since it doesn't matter, what would be the primer you would recommend for my situation? The paint I will be using is Kelli Moore Magnum in eggshell.

Comment: Recommendations for specific products are outside the scope of any Stack Exchange site. If it were me, I would consult with the same retailer from whom I'm buying the wall paint, to have them suggest an appropriate primer that can be used over both old paint and drywall compound. I would expect that simply using _any_ good primer is more important than which one specifically, but your retailer may have something more specific in mind.